# haproxy.service start failed when I set up load balancer on the same machine which serves the website

Tags: apache, server, load-balancing, haproxy, hosts

I have 2 machines

```
192.46.209.80 # server1
192.46.209.82 # server2
```

I was setting up HAProxy load balancer on the same machine server1 which is also serving my website.
So now server1 will be running HAProxy as well as the webserver.
I setup Apache2 and HAProxy according to this [tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/how-to-install-and-configure-haproxy-load-balancer-in-linux/)

On **192.46.209.80** server1 this is my **hosts** file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
HAproxy 192.46.209.80
192.46.209.80 HAProxy
192.46.209.80 server1
192.46.209.82 server2
```

On **192.46.209.82** server2 this is my **hosts** file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost

The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
HAproxy 192.46.209.80
```

then after installing HAProxy on server1

```
sudo sudo apt install haproxy
```

I edited and appended in **sudo nano /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg**

```
#HAProxy for web servers
frontend web-frontend
  bind 192.46.209.80:80
  mode http
  default_backend web-backend

backend web-backend
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 192.46.209.80 check port 80
  server server2 192.46.209.82 check port 80
```

After running

```
sudo systemctl restart haproxy.service
```

I am getting error

```
Job for haproxy.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status haproxy.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

This is the result of `journalctl -xe`

```
-- Subject: Unit process exited
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- An ExecStart= process belonging to unit haproxy.service has exited.
--
-- The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit haproxy.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
-- Subject: A start job for unit haproxy.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit haproxy.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 6245 and the job result is failed.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
-- Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Automatic restarting of the unit haproxy.service has been scheduled, as the result for
-- the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped HAProxy Load Balancer.
-- Subject: A stop job for unit haproxy.service has finished
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A stop job for unit haproxy.service has finished.
--
-- The job identifier is 6314 and the job result is done.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: haproxy.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
-- Subject: Unit failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The unit haproxy.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Oct 19 14:13:18 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start HAProxy Load Balancer.
-- Subject: A start job for unit haproxy.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- A start job for unit haproxy.service has finished with a failure.
--
-- The job identifier is 6314 and the job result is failed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my Apache web server is listening on Port 80, therefore I cannot configure the same for my HAProxy.

Changed it to another port and it worked.

```
frontend web-frontend
  bind 192.46.209.80:541
  mode http
  default_backend web-backend

backend web-backend
  balance roundrobin
  server server1 192.46.209.80 check port 80
  server server2 192.46.209.82 check port 80
```